# Calculate length of a signal

Tags: python, signal-processing

I want to calculate the length of a signal. By length I don't mean the number of points, but the actual distance from point to point. Imagine that a person would walk along the signal, what would be the distance traveled?

The points are evenly spaced on the x-axis. This should probably be done via integration, but I currently do it like this:

```
length = np.sum(np.sqrt(np.diff(y)**2))
```

Is this sufficient to give me the correct length?

The reason why I want to do this is because I want to compare the length of the signal before and after smoothing. How much it shortens through smoothing should be used as a metric to describe signal 'roughness'.

In theory, the length I want to calculate is defined like:

$$
l(\sigma) = \int \sqrt{1 + (x * g_\sigma(t))} \;dt
$$

where $x$ is the signal and $g$ is the kernel it is smoothed with.

Edit:

I realized that the code above is not valid because the points are not necessarily connected linearly. What I want to now is calculating the length of a curve by implementing the term below.

How can I approach this if I want to start with data points? Do I need to fit a polynomial to my data and then need some for a symbolic computation?

[image]

Comment: Could you give us more details? How exactly was it smoothed? What exactly do you mean by the length of the signal?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but could you tell us what are you trying to achieve by that? What do you mean by "distance"? How do you want to use it? The "correct length" depends on what you mean by "length". If you define it as the total squared difference between subsequent points, then by definition what you are calculating is correct.

Comment: And by this definition a smoothed signal would be shorter than a raw signal, as there is less up and down? What I am trying to achieve is to generate a log-log plot where x ist the degree of smoothing and y is the signal length. the slope of this curve is a characteristic for signal roughness,

Comment: added a formula to make it clearer what i mean by length.

Comment: what's the problem with using the supplied python expression?

Comment: Hi, just wanted to make sure that I am calculating the correct thing.

Comment: Am I right that the python code only works with evenly spaced points?

Comment: Rissanen's *minimum description length* deserves mention, an information theoretic concept. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_description_length